# Scraping a paginated website with the same URL when clicking the "next page" button

Tags: r, web-scraping, pagination, rvest

I am new to R and sorry in advance if my question is too basic.

I am scrapping a website (here's the link: http://jhsjk.people.cn/result?type ) to download all the articles. I noted that every time I click the next page button, the url remain unchanged.

I try to use `rvest` loop function to scrape the next page, but failed.

I searched on this website and learned that i might use `RSelenium` package to get myself there, but I still could sort this out :( (I am so stupid on this)

here's my code

```
url <- c("http://jhsjk.people.cn/result?type").
page<-read_html(url).     
title <- page %>% html_nodes(css=".btbg .w1200.p2_cn.cf #news_list.list_14.p1_2.clearfix a" ) %>% html_text (). 
link <- page %>% html_elements(css=".btbg .w1200.p2_cn.cf #news_list.list_14.p1_2.clearfix a") %>% html_attr('href')
press_releases_df <- data.frame( title = title, link = link)
```

with this code, i can only extract the first page,I want to use loop function,but don't really know what should be looped. should it be the page number?

Comment: Please add your code, otherwise there's not much people can do to help you.

Comment: I tried to add, but i cannot attach a picture to it :(

Comment: I'm quite sure it will, you just messed up the formatting somehow. And instead of picture, add the actual text instead.

Comment: thanks! i added the code. this is where I am at this stage. I can't identify what to loop in this case. The URL remains the same every time I scroll to another page.

Comment: try using `RSelenium`

Comment: I do not read chinese, but if you open the network analysis on your browser, you can see that the URL seems to not change, but actually there is a new get request. Instead of overcomplicating it with Rselenium, just write a for loop and adjust the page number in the following link `http://jhsjk.people.cn/testnew/result?keywords=&isFuzzy=0&searchArea=0&year=0&form=0&type=0&page=3&origin=全部&source=2`